# How to connect two points in Google Chart Tools - Scatter Chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, scatter-plot

I use Google Chart Tools to draw simple graph with some missing data. With my code, I get something like on this image:

[image]

Is it possible to connect points (1) and (4) with line similar to (4) - (5) connection? Maybe I could use another type of graph to achieve the same result? I tried Area Chart with `interpolateNulls` option, but the result was the same. It can interpolate only `NULL`s surrounded by some date, not two or more `NULLs` in a row.

Below is sample code:

```js
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'Year');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
  data.addRows([
    [1, 1000],
    [2, null],
    [3, null],
    [4, 1030],
    [5, 1080]
  ]);
  var options = {
    'title'     : 'Line chart',
    'width'     : 400,
    'height'    : 300,
    'lineWidth' : 2
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="chart_div"></div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar problem here:[Google chart line: how to connect dots properly using a continuous axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078528/google-chart-line-how-to-connect-dots-properly-using-a-continuous-axes)

The answer to your question was on one of the comments:

'If the value you are trying to pass is through some xml or json and it has null values inside it will not plot properly and will be scattered or as dotted lines in line graph so to plot them, have a condition to remove all null values and then it will plot correctly.' by @Taher SK